# using two regular expressions to search a file

Tags: python, regex

Both my regular expressions work, what I am trying to do is have the first one read the file and print every time there is a match(this works) then when it finds a match for the second expression it prints a match for it.  So in the file I am importing, it will match all the numbers then once it finds 'BREAK' it print 'BREAK'.  What I am getting is that it prints 'BREAK' after every number it finds a match for.  My goal is to stop the search for matching number once the program sees the word 'BREAK'.

```
      for m in re.finditer(r'((((2)([0-3]))|(([0-1])([0-9])))([0-5])([0-9]))', text):
        print(m.group(0))
        l=re.search(r'(BREAK)', text)
        if l:
            print(l.group(0))
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Aaron, this line `l=re.search(r'(BREAK)', text)` starts the search from the beginning of text, again and again, when a new number is found

Comment: Maybe you should have added a little sample input text and expected output. Form me it is not quite straightforward what you want. My guess is that you want to read your file line by line, and check if a certain line matches one of your patterns. Also you will want to save _state_ into a variable. So you will know your previous matches. Hope this helps.

Comment: here is some sample input,     
hi there May 12, -1956
BREAK
June -12, 2311
the output would be 1956

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when you search for "BREAK" you are searching the whole text and not the text that appears after the number you found. Because of this, if the text has "BREAK" anywhere in it, it will always be found.

It seems like `finditer()` might not be the best thing to use for your situation. It would be better to iterate over the lines of the file yourself and you will have more control over the looping.

```
with open("test.txt") as f:
  for line in f:
    if re.match("BREAK", line):
      print("Break")
      break
    m = re.match(r'((((2)([0-3]))|(([0-1])([0-9])))([0-5])([0-9]))', line)
    if m:
      print(m.group(0))
```

Comment: Thanks I had to play around with it a little to make my code work, but it works

Answer (score 0):

You evidently need to do :

```
import re

text = '''-- 000 == 111 ** 222
@@ 444 ## 555 BREAK 666 :::
777 ,,, 888 &&&'''

regx = re.compile('\d(\d)\d')
brek = text.find('BREAK')
li = [m.group() for m in regx.finditer(text,0,(brek if brek+1 else len(text)))]
print li
print
print '\n'.join(li)
```

result

```
['000', '111', '222', '444', '555']

000
111
222
444
555
```